# What is viewer2D(or viewer3D).isolate exactly doing? And why it is necessary?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am working on something similar to this [demo](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-viewer-samples/blob/master/public/aec-mapping-2d-to-3d.html)

And I would like to know why `viewer3D.isolate(...node?)` of line 75 is necessary and why I should use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isolate` is one of the viewer methods that can be used to visually distinguish one or more design elements, for example:

- `viewer.select(ids)` can be used to *select* design elements; this will give them a specific selection color (blue by default) highlight
- `viewer.isolate(ids)` can be used to *isolate* design elements; this will make any non-isolated elements semi-transparent or completely transparent (depending on your user settings)
- `viewer.setThemingColor(id, color)` can be used to apply a custom color tint to specific design element

As for the specific line `viewer.isolate([])`, this basically says "isolate nothing", or in other words, "reset isolation and make all objects visible again".

Comment: Nice to see you answer my question again. @Petr And it is the answer that I want so thank you very much again.